# adding activityIndicator when downloading many files iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm downloading many pdf files using this code

```
for (int i=0; i<[myBooks count]; i++) {

Book_own *temp= (Book_own *)[myBooks objectAtIndex:i]; // myBooks is a mutable array of object Book_own

     // to download pdf
     NSString *documentName = [temp.bo_path stringByDeletingPathExtension];

     NSString *pdfLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://url.com/files/%@",temp.bo_path];

     NSString *linkWithoutSpaces = [pdfLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];

     NSString *urlString = linkWithoutSpaces;

     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

     NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

     NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

     NSString *documentDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];

     NSLog(@"in settings, Document Directory: %@",documentDir);

     NSString *pdfPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentDir,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf",documentName]];

      NSLog(@"pdfpath: %@",pdfPath);

      [data writeToFile:pdfPath atomically:YES];
      NSData *tmp = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

      if (tmp != nil) {
         NSError *error = nil;
         [tmp writeToFile:pdfPath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
         if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Failed to save the file: %@", [error description]);
             } else {
               NSLog(@"downloaded");
             }
           } else {
               NSLog(@"fail to save pdf file");
              }
 }
```

this downloads files for me, but It makes me waiting for a long time and I want to add activityIndicator or progress bar to show me the downloading progress.
but I'm new in iPhone and I have no idea how to do this.
can anyone help me?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to do much with this anyway. The way you're downloading data is thoroughly blocking the main thread. I suggest looking into downloading data asynchronously using `NSURLRequest`'s in a `NSOperationQueue`.

Comment: could you show me how please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can use below function for depicting indicator, which is added on a view:(showing indicator at amid of screen)

-(void)showActivityIndicatorViewer
{
    AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UIWindow *window = delegate.window;
    activityView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, window.bounds.size.width, window.bounds.size.height)];
    activityView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    activityView.alpha = 0.5;

    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityWheel = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(window.bounds.size.width / 2 - 12, window.bounds.size.height / 2 - 12, 24, 24)];
    activityWheel.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite;
    activityWheel.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
                                      UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
                                      UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
                                      UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin);
    [activityView addSubview:activityWheel];
    [window addSubview: activityView];

    [[[activityView subviews] objectAtIndex:0] startAnimating];
}

-(void)hideActivityIndicatorViewer
{
    [[[activityView subviews] objectAtIndex:0] stopAnimating];
    [activityView removeFromSuperview];
    activityView = nil;
}

While, if you just want default(shown at top of status bar):

Also, you can third party like HUD, you just google it, you'll find how yo use it.
```

Comment: And, if you want ios default, which is shown at amid of status bar, use that: UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;(NO, when you think to hide)

Answer (score 2):

There are many custom classes for activity indicators.Since you are new to iphone.I suggest the default activity indicator in xcode.

1)Drag and drop the UIActivityIndicator object to your Interface builder.

Write the following code in the .h file of your viewcontroller:

```
    IBOutlet  UIActivityIndicator *activityIndicator;
    //connect this outlet to the xib.
```

in your .m file:

```
       //when u call the method
      [activityIndicator startanimating];
      //when everything is complete
      [activityIndicator stopanimating];
```

hope this helps you to give it a start.

Answer (score 1):

I found a good example

in .h file

```
UIAlertView *progressAlert;
```

in .m file

```
-(void)showAlertMethod

{
 progressAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Uploading please wait...\n" message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
CGRect alertFrame = progressAlert.frame;
UIActivityIndicatorView* activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(135,alertFrame.size.height+55, alertFrame.size.width,30);
activityIndicator.hidden = NO;
activityIndicator.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
[activityIndicator startAnimating]; 
[progressAlert addSubview:activityIndicator];
[progressAlert show];

}
-(void)dismissAlertMethod
{
[progressAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

call the method according to your requirements. I call the methods in this way:-

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(showAlertMethod) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(dismissAlertMethod) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

[MBProgressuHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) is a very good and easy to use drop-in class to show activity indicator.

Also you should definitely download your files asynchronously. In the demo project I think there are a couple of different examples with NSURLConnection and GCD.

Comment: thanks for your answer I watched this example but it shows me how to use the different types of activity indicators but I want to know to to add it to the code of download file meaning I want an example of this.

Answer (score 0):

1. offload it to a second thread:

   ```
   [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(downloadAll)];
   ```
2. show Indicator UI before the download

   ```
   //MOCKUP UI
   indicator = [[UIActivityIndicator alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,50,50)];
   self.view addSubView:indicator];
   [indicator startAnimating];

   [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(downloadAll)];
   ```
3. AFTER download callback main thread

   ```
   - (void)downloadAll {
       //...... YOUR DOWNLOAD CODE
       [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(downloadDone) waitUntilDone:NO];
   }
   ```
4. in downloadDone hide indiator

   ```
   - (void)downloadDone {
       [self.indicator stopAnimating];
       [self.indicator removeFromSuperview];
   }
   ```

Comment: typed inline and tested but that the general procedure :D

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I can't understand your mean of `offload it to a second thread: [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(downloadAll)];` and in 2 the xcode suggested to replace UIActivityIndicator by UIActivityIndicatorView and the `[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(downloadAll)];` is must be as `[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(downloadAll) withObject:nil];` also in 3 the `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(downloadDone) waitUntilDone:NO];` must be as `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(downloadDone) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];`

Comment: and I preferred to add the activity indicator to alert view so I wrote the following ` myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Downloading..." message:@"\n\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
indicator.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,50,50);
[myAlertView addSubview:indicator];
[indicator startAnimating];
[myAlertView show];
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(downloadAll) withObject:nil];` but the activity indicator not appears :(